# Evaluating $\int _{ 0 }^{ \pi }{ { e }^{ { \sin ^{ 2 } x } } } { \cos((2n+1)x) }dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to find the following integral?

$$\int _{ 0 }^{ \pi  }{ { e }^{ { \sin ^{ 2 } x } } } { \cos((2n+1)x) } dx$$

Just give me some hints (hints only) so that I can proceed.

Comment: Is the $x$ in the cosine part?

Comment: Yes @AhmedS.Attaalla

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla A standard form of the integral might not exist.But since limits are given surely the area under the curve can be found.BTW its from a study material .

Comment: @SanchayanDutta is 'n' an integer?

Comment: @Rishi yes indeed

Comment: **Hint:** The main idea is that $\cos\Big((2n+1)x\Big)$ is always a [polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the form $$\sum_{k+j=n}a_k\cdot\cos^{2k+1}x\cdot\sin^{2j}x.$$ Factoring $\cos x$ outside the sum, and using $\cos^{2k}x=(1-\sin^2x)^k$ in conjunction with $\sin'x=\cos x$ yields the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I=$\int _{ 0 }^{ \pi  }{ { e }^{ { \sin ^{ 2 } x } } } { \cos((2n+1)x) } dx$

Let $u=\pi -x$, $dx=-du$,

$${ { e }^{ { \sin ^{ 2 } x } } }={ { e }^{ { \sin ^{ 2 }( {\pi -u} )} } }={ { e }^{ { \sin ^{ 2 } u } } }$$,

${ \cos((2n+1)x) }$=
${ \cos((2n+1)(\pi-u) }$=
${ \cos(2n\pi + (\pi - (2n+1)u)) }$= 
${ \cos(\pi - (2n+1)u)) }$=
$-{ \cos(2n+1)u)) }$

Therefore, $$I=\int _{ \pi }^{ 0  }{ { e }^{ { \sin ^{ 2 } u } } } ({- \cos((2n+1)u) }) (-du)$$  $$=-\int _{ 0 }^{ \pi  }{ { e }^{ { \sin ^{ 2 } x } } } { \cos((2n+1)x) } dx$$ $$=-I$$

$$I + I = 0$$

$$2I = 0$$

$$I = 0$$

Hence the integral is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You can make $x=t+\frac{\pi}{2}$, so
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi}{e^{\sin^2 x}\cos((2n+1)x) dx}&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}{e^{1-\cos^2 (t+\frac{\pi}{2})}\cos\left((2n+1)t+n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right) dt}\tag{1}
\end{align}
Also, if $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have 
\begin{align}
\cos\left((2n+1)t+n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)&=\cos [(2n+1)t]\cos\left(n\pi +\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\sin[(2n+1)t]\sin\left(n\pi +\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
&=0-(-1)^n\sin[(2n+1)t]\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}\sin[(2n+1)t]
\end{align}
Then the integrand in ($1$) is odd

Comment: Really nice...but how did you come up with such a strange substitution...?

Comment: @SanchayanDutta: Generally, symmetric intervals give an easier way in order to evaluate integrands containing trigonometric functions. I think that using integration by parts can works too.